# Setting booleans in an Array upon an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a function which is triggered on a click event.

Basically, I have two elements which are objects inside an array called `chosenChar`. Both of the objects begin with a boolean property called `isAttacker` as false.

When an "attack" button is clicked, the idea is to choose one of the objects in the array at random and change its `isAttacker` boolean to true. Also, we dive into that attacker object, grab an attack from an array within the object, get the attack value, and print that to the screen.

My object here is if I set the attacker boolean to true, the remaining element in the original array must be set to false (as it is originally) and I need to calculate the damage done to the defending object (character).

Everything is console logging "true" right now and it's not going into the if statement to find out if there is a defender and calculating the character's health based off the attack.

```
var attackChar = [];
var defendingChar = [];

// get a random character to attack
attackChar = chosenChar[Math.floor(Math.random()*chosenChar.length)];
var attackCharName = attackChar.name;
attackChar.isAttacker = true;
console.log("the attacker is " + attackChar.name + " and isAttacker is " + attackChar.isAttacker);

for (var i = 0; i < chosenChar.length; i++) {
    if(chosenChar[i].isAttacker === true) {
       console.log(chosenChar[i].name + " is the attacker");
    } else {
       console.log(chosenChar[i].name + " is not the attacker");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please update your post and clarify your question?

Comment: Okay. I did that.

Comment: Why would the `chosenChar` array have a property named `isAttacker`?

Comment: the objects within chosenChar array each have a property of isAttacker. I felt it may be simpler to use a boolean than to push each object into two distinct arrays

Comment: So, are you asking how to set the elements in the array to false? Or something else? That's what needs clarification: what is your question?

Comment: *"the objects within ... have a property"*: yes, but in the `if` you are using the property on the array itself, not the objects within.

Comment: yes. It's supposed to be a game. A user chooses two characters to duel. Those two characters are put into the chosenChar array. On each button click, they fight, and attacks and damages are called at random. But I need to know which is the random attacker and which is the defender to calculate their health adjustments. I thought putting a boolean isAttacker as a property and have it set to false at the start then switching it to true would work.

Comment: @J.G.Sable : but you are checking if `chosenChar.isAttacker` is false, but setting `attackChar.isAttacker` to true.  We're confused as to why `chosenChar` has a `isAttacker` property when it appears to be the "container" holding the characters.  Shouldn't you be looking at `attackChar.isAttacker` ?  And if so, it will always be true at that point in your code because you set it to true just a few lines above the if condition.

Comment: @devlincarnate yes, I see your point. I updated my post with some new codde that is closer, but the for-loop isn't returning the correct values every time.

Comment: When you decide on who is the attacker, you need to set all of the other `isAttacker` values to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've selected the `attackChar`, you can loop over all of the characters and set the `isAttacker` flag to false for all of them except the new attacker.

```
attackChar = chosenChar[Math.floor(Math.random()*chosenChar.length)];
var attackCharName = attackChar.name;

// set isAttacker to true/false based on the attackChar
chosenChar.forEach(function(char) {
    char.isAttacker = char === attackChar;
});

for (var i = 0; i < chosenChar.length; i++) {
    if(chosenChar[i].isAttacker === true) {
       console.log(chosenChar[i].name + " is the attacker");
    } else {
       console.log(chosenChar[i].name + " is not the attacker");
    }
}
```

Another way of doing this is to have a separate value that holds the attacker, instead of updating an `isAttacker` value on each character.

You've actually already done this (`chosenChar`), so the `isAttacker` value isn't technically necessary, but you may find it more convenient than depending on a separate variable floating around.

```
attackChar = chosenChar[Math.floor(Math.random()*chosenChar.length)];
for (var i = 0; i < chosenChar.length; i++) {
    if(chosenChar[i] === attackChar) {
       console.log(chosenChar[i].name + " is the attacker");
    } else {
       console.log(chosenChar[i].name + " is not the attacker");
    }
}
```